# Redis RDB occurs even with AOF and Snapshotting turned off (and possibly leads to complete key loss)

Tags: redis

We're running Redis 5.0.3 on docker, with both saving and AOF turned off:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get save
1) "save"
2) ""
127.0.0.1:6379> config get appendonly
1) "appendonly"
2) "no"
```

Everything runs fine (no backups in the logs), until this morning when we got several DB backup logs in quick succession:

```
21 Mar 2019 04:12:58.453 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:12:58.454 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:12:58.456 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:13:50.153 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:13:51.573 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:13:52.282 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:21:18.539 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:21:18.540 * DB saved on disk
21 Mar 2019 04:21:18.541 * DB saved on disk
```

During this time period, *Redis drops all of our keys* - twice!

Any ideas why this is happening? The system is not under memory or CPU pressure, all graphs look normal.

Other useful things:

- Memory usage of redis is increasing but still well within the bounds of the box (as expected as we're storing streams of data)
- Number of keys is flat during this time period, until they all get dropped
- Latency is flat the whole time
- Redis reports no expired or evicted keys
- The slow log bumps up during that time period and then is flat again immediately after.

## EDIT

On further debugging using `info commandstats` it seems that several `flushall` commands were made during this time period, which would explain the DB saves from looking at source.

I have no idea why these flushes are occurring - we do not have any flush commands in our applications. Debugging continues.